# Cannot open office apps in web browser mode from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, sharepoint-2016, office-online-server

I've installed Microsoft office web apps offline in the VM and also Installed SharePoint 2016 in another VM machine. Both VMs are connected to the domain.

Besides, I've successfully connected SharePoint to the office farm. But when I try to open `docx` files or any other office app on the web browser I get the below error :

[image]

Comment: as it is stated here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes#14-scheme-names-and-office-application-registrations

The error that you get might possibly mean that the browser is trying to open the MS Word Desktop App and the app might not be registered as a Scheme Name.
Have you installed Microsoft Office on the machine that you are accessing SharePoint ?

Comment: jimas13 Tnx for your response. But I wanna open office apps remotely on the web browser not on my local machine. So, I don't have any installed office app on my machine. How can I handle this problem??

Comment: you mean that you want to open the document by opening the MS Word in Web Browser mode ? correct?

Comment: jimas13 yes exactly.

Comment: i have added my answer on the topic. please check below.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to launch 'ms-word:ofv%7Cu%7Chttp://....' because the scheme
> does not have a registered handler.

Based on the error that you have screenshoted, the Application falied to launch the MS Word Desktop Client because the scheme "ms-word" does not have a handler registered, which in simple terms means that there isn't any associated app to execute when the beforementioned scheme is used and in order to have the scheme registered with an application, you would have to install Microsoft Office on the machine that you are using to view the SharePoint Site.

[Here is the link to the documentation where is states that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes#14-scheme-names-and-office-application-registrations) the scheme handlers are registered upon the installation of Microsoft Office.

> The following is the list of scheme names implemented in Microsoft Office applications. When Microsoft Office is installed, each scheme name is registered with Windows to be handled by the Office product of the same name. Note that "ms-spd" is an abbreviation for SharePoint Designer.
>
> ms-word:

But in order to use the Web counterparts of the Office apps, like Word or Excel in the browser, there is a different procedure where it is required of you to Install a [Office Online Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server-overview) and enable communication with SharePoint Server.

As it is written in the overview of the product...

> Office Online Server delivers browser-based versions of Word, PowerPoint, Excel, and OneNote. A single Office Online Server farm can support users who access Office files through SharePoint Server, Exchange Server, shared folders, and web sites.

Since it's a lengthy procedure and there are different prerequisites in term of licensing and other matters, you can check out this [link (Configure Office Online Server for SharePoint Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016/configure-office-online-server-for-sharepoint-server-2016#before-you-configure-sharepoint-server-to-use-office-online-server) on the topic and decide which features you are looking for.

Comment: jimas13 Tnx for your complete response. I know to edit documents I need license But I can't even open any document in the browser and think for opening document I don't need any license !!!

Comment: @al fk hey, no problem! Unfortunately, a license is required in all circumstances

Comment: jimas13 , Should I download requirement licenses ??

Comment: @al fk, i don't know what the "requirement licenses" are.